# Can't remove/upload file through aspuploader

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have tried to remove an image but I can't. It works fine but sometime it generates an error. And I have also provided full permission on directory.

Error Message:

```
Persist.Upload.1 error '800a001d' Access is denied.
```

Comment: I'm sure that you're not using `ASP.NET` and `ASP classic` at the same time, so remove either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try give the full permission to user "Everyone" of this folder.